# Crystal report - Trouble finding the right formula

Tags: stored-procedures, crystal-reports, formula

I am working with this report and I'm having a hard time finding the formula for this scenario.I want the payment amount to be distributed in `school fees` and  `fills the fee with the least amount first` below is the current report I've created.

I have this stored procedure that gets the fees above and the payments below is in the details section of the crystal report.

Here is a clear example:

The initial payment is **500** 
The least fees is internet fee with the amount of **376.20**
**500-376.20 = 123.80** 
so the remaining **123.80** will be going to the other fee which is **752.40**
**752.40 - 123.80 = 628.60**(remaining balance of the other fee)

What I want to know is there a possible way to do this

[image: Report]

What formula do I use to produce such output below.
[image: ast]

Comment: From the question I am unable to understand your exact requirement.. Can you be more precise and specific?

Comment: Formula should be easy to make, but we really need to know abit more.  Is the payment distribution fixed or a % of the payment.  Also, is there a criteria you follow for the payment to be distributed amongst the columns.  The 500$ its the Other Fees and Internet, but the 3,750$ hits Misc, Special Fee, and Other Fee.   Do certain columns get priority over the other?

Comment: yes because other fee still have a balance of 601.60. Regarding with the columns they are prioritize based on there current balance remaining.

Comment: So the order should be: `internet fee`, `other fee`, `misc`, `special fee`, `lab`?

Comment: Yes the order should be determine by the amount of each fee.

Comment: @PrinceJea: would you post some example code that illustrates your approach?

Comment: @PrinceJea from your stored procedure, are you able to return a list of fees sorted in descending order?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two formula fields, Formula1 and Formula2,
In Formula1 add this operation :

```
 Formula = Ammount - InternetFee
```

In Formula2 add this operation :

```
 Formula = OtherFee - Formula1
```

you can drag drop formula1 into formula2 from report fields in formula tool bar